# Embedding web font, do I need to include all of these: "ttf, eot, woff and svg"?

Tags: android, css, fonts

I'm using a unique font for a web app that will be built using phone gap and deployed to Android. For android do I need to include all these different formats?

```
ttf, eot, woff and svg
```

I would rather not load a bunch of font files if they aren't necessary.

Comment: For Android you will definitely not need the eot. The other formats, well, it depends on how many versions back you want to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't hurt, TTF, SVG are widely used, EOT is not supported at all. The browser should only load one font file not all four so it doesn't hurt to have then declared for support sake.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf

http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff

http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot

Comment: Ahh perfect, didn't know the browser ignores the ones it doesn't need.

Answer (score 0):

If you can can (ie you have font in that format) just use ttf fonts on android.